# How to constraint the return type of a function based on JSX?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I would like to create a function that the return type should return a particular JSX type.

For example:

```
const setHosting : <GitlabLogo> | <GithubLogo> = (h: Hosting) => ???
```

Here the return type should be either `<GitlabLogo>` or `<GithubLogo>`. Is it possible?

Comment: If you want to return these _exact_ components, you should return `GitlabLogo`, and _not_ `<GitlabLogo>`. If you want to return the latter form, and there's no unique properties or results, your only choice is something generic like `React.Component`, `React.Node`, `React.FunctionComponent`.

Comment: I tried `const setHosting = (h: Hosting): (GitlabLogo | GithubLogo>) => ` but it does not work.

Comment: You have 25K reputation so you must know at this point that 'does not work' is not very helpful =). Try to add a minimal reproducable example + error output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short -- no, it's not possible.

If you want the function to return the JSX element (ie. `<GithubLogo />`) then you cannot require that it be of particular type because all JSX elements are just type `JSX.Element`.

If you want the function to return the *component* (ie. `GithubLogo`) then you can do a little bit better, but not much better.  Keep in mind that Typescript is structurally rather than nominally typed. If `GitlabLogo` is a function component that takes no props and returns a `JSX.Element` then **any**  function component with no props is assignable to `typeof GitlabLogo`.  So you cannot require a particular component.  You can only require a particular props type.

```
type Hosting = "gitlab" | "github";

// return an element
const setHostingA = (h: Hosting): JSX.Element => h === "github" ? <GithubLogo/> : <GitlabLogo/>;

// return a component
const setHostingB = (h: Hosting): React.ComponentType<{}> => h === "github" ? GithubLogo : GitlabLogo;
const HostingComponent = setHostingB("github");
const element = <HostingComponent/>

// call as a component - return an element
const HostingLogo = ({hosting}: {hosting: Hosting}): JSX.Element => {
    const Component = hosting === "github" ? GithubLogo : GitlabLogo;
    return <Component/>;
}
const a = <HostingLogo hosting="github"/>;
const b = <HostingLogo hosting="gitlab"/>;
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4BxYGAGxQCMAZCAcwjgBeOAAoAlEIB8cADyhecOlDSD8%20OClYxVvFuw74A9JMpp2dOnGYwAFgFdufAUgAeMJDQAml5OhgA6AGFcSBoPGABvcjgYuCIvJChxOCjYtLikGDsoGlFo9IK5EAUlFTUNLR07WwcjEwKYsXyYgF9yFrhKGABPMCQ4AAkIBmAaBWF8XTZOdQAfAin7AwpyQ0MMrJyNXKRWJBBwqloGRUyhkbGAQSFRGwAuQeGYUd4xB4ApAGUADX8AUT2Bxo8EE0hsQkEE0WtTgAH5ZNYljx%20MY4A8ZNZ9MiIMYVmsNtlcig4NRwLRDtR6PA6Gcni8AEI3ET3R4XV4PXwYIIhcnAgAqvSQMgiLWkoLg4MhUJYS3U8MRDmxaKsek42IolJO52eY2CZLCwJuNJg2oZIkmMtqYg1x3gu324RuMlNup5Bpgxko%20LQmlYGksxNJoUdAFoCVsUDtARTbaydbwlcIRBEbHSxi0Him07wHi7eC03nAvr8AQ7DeLUrFNfA9cHyxLsxDpTUDHCVS2lQ9MWqnBQ0kRNrkZLXeR7JBQ2tWNE680rU2ydJaDLijlS4BwZ9m59nF9Nl%20OgA)